# How to draw this image and how to put text inside the drawing? Please, help with the code ASAP

Tags: graphics, draw, tikz-graphdrawing

[image]

I'm new at this and I really need help to draw it in Latex.

Comment: You got an answer this time around, but at this site, we generally want you to show us what work you already have, so that we can get you unstuck.  As it stands, the best answer to "I'm new at this" is "you should find a tutorial for drawing in LaTeX."

Answer (score 3):

Please use never ASAP in a question again.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[thin] foreach \X in {0.1,0.2,...,4.9}
  {(\X,0) -- (\X,0.2)};
 \draw[thin] foreach \X in {0.5,1,...,4.5}
  {(\X,0) -- (\X,0.3)}; 
 \draw (0,0)  -- (5,0) foreach \X in {0,1,...,5}
  {(\X,0) -- (\X,0.5) node[above]{\ifnum\X=0\relax \textsc{CM}\else $\X$  \fi}};
 \draw (1,2) rectangle (3.5,3) node[midway] {text}
  foreach \X in {1.5,3} {(\X,1.6) node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] {}circle[radius=0.35cm]};
 \draw[-latex] (1,3) -- (0,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

with https://www.mathcha.io/

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}




\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp48852170770045333] 
\draw   (100,125) -- (282,125) -- (282,165) -- (100,165) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp7086230022754691] 
\draw   (100,192.5) .. controls (100,183.39) and (107.39,176) .. (116.5,176) .. controls (125.61,176) and (133,183.39) .. (133,192.5) .. controls (133,201.61) and (125.61,209) .. (116.5,209) .. controls (107.39,209) and (100,201.61) .. (100,192.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp15885146101790903] 
\draw   (245,193.5) .. controls (245,184.39) and (252.39,177) .. (261.5,177) .. controls (270.61,177) and (278,184.39) .. (278,193.5) .. controls (278,202.61) and (270.61,210) .. (261.5,210) .. controls (252.39,210) and (245,202.61) .. (245,193.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp6188324583058722] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (111,192.5) .. controls (111,189.46) and (113.46,187) .. (116.5,187) .. controls (119.54,187) and (122,189.46) .. (122,192.5) .. controls (122,195.54) and (119.54,198) .. (116.5,198) .. controls (113.46,198) and (111,195.54) .. (111,192.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp6268195745331264] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (256,193.5) .. controls (256,190.46) and (258.46,188) .. (261.5,188) .. controls (264.54,188) and (267,190.46) .. (267,193.5) .. controls (267,196.54) and (264.54,199) .. (261.5,199) .. controls (258.46,199) and (256,196.54) .. (256,193.5) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6035408403138598] 
\draw    (100,128) -- (45.23,57.58) ;
\draw [shift={(44,56)}, rotate = 412.13] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;


% Text Node
\draw (191,145) node  [align=left] {text};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: omg, i've got an answer so fast. thank you so much<3
you did it with online mathcha, right?

Comment: @ValerieSmith Yes, online mathcha and export to tikz

Comment: @ian: Your approach is rather ineffective.

Comment: @MarianG. It produces an image in less than one minute, how is that ineffective?

Comment: @ian: The code is chaotic. You can use only few commands to produce such simple output.

Comment: @MarianG. If this is so simple, why is there no answer from you?

Comment: @ian: I'm too busy right now. I'll try it later.

Comment: @ian you may have produced code *fast*, but you didn't produce *good* code. Such code is throw-away code: you can use it once but seldom adapt it. And no, I won't make a better version. I don't answer such boring "draw it for me"-questions, even less if they shout "ASAP".

Comment: thanks to @ian anyway, bc it's working and other doesn't matter for me